# list item reflected on different sites

Tags: sharepoint-designer

At this time we only have the ability to use SharePoint Designer, not Visual Studio.

We have a list that has info about projects. for each project we create a site. We store the list on the top site, and the projects are subs of that. What we are wanting to do is in the sub have the info about this project from the list reflected in that site.

Example :   site A (list abides here) list has projects (1,2,3,4,5,6)
                 site a1 (needs info from list but only list item 1)
                 site a2 (needs info from list but only list item 2)
                 site a3 (needs info from list but only list item 3)

Is this possible with the tools that we have?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use list web parts outside the site where the list belong.

Instead you can use Content Query Web Part (CQWP) to fetch data from the root site list.

Instead of using item 1,2,3 you will have to create a site column with a choice list (could also be a Taxonomy field or even a data bound BCS field) in the list on the root web, containing project ID / type / similar.

Then for each item set the project ID / type for that item.

On the given sub site you can then filter on that ID / type manually.

If you want this to happen in a more automated fashion, and you are using SharePoint 2010 and publishing pages, you could use the dynamic filtering option in CQWP. To do this you would need to add the site column to your publishing content type and then in the CQWP filter on [PageFieldValue: yourFieldName]